# Silent printer install via Point-To-Point printing

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, cmd

I'm having trouble with a silent installation script for printers on Windows 10 1709.
We have an installation script that does the following.

1. Make a connection with the printserver via net use.
2. Import Point-To-Point registry file
3. Install the printers
4. Remove Point-To-Point registry keys and values

This works fine for our Server 2008 computers. I have to do the same trick for Windows 10 1709 computers. Only with a few (not all) printers, i get the following error.

[image]

When i install the printer by hand, it works fine. I get a popup that says i have to trust the printer. When i click on install drivers, it installs the printer. It just wont silently install.

Here are the installation scripts.

**Install:**

```
echo "Import Point And Print Settings" 
reg import PointAndPrint.reg

REM Aanmelden Print Server
net use \\print01\IPC$ /USER:**** *******

echo "Install Printer Drivers" 

rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n\\print01\HPLJ-M201n-WSN-Timmerwerkplts
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n\\print01\Zebra-DIV-VS
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n\\print01\HPLJ-M127fn-CJG_WSN
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n\\print01\B8065-Fractiekamer
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n\\print01\BrotherQL720NW
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n\\print01\MP2401-GKW-PLOTTER

echo "Import Point and Print"
reg import RemovePointAndPrint.reg
```

**Registry:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\PointAndPrint]
"Restricted"=dword:00000001
"TrustedServers"=dword:00000001
"ServerList"="PRINT01;PRINT01.domain.local"
"InForest"=dword:00000001
"NoWarningNoElevationOnInstall"=dword:00000001
"UpdatePromptSettings"=dword:00000002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Procmon to see what happended when you "Trust the printserver" if you manually installed it.

This registry setting was set:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\LegacyPointAndPrint]
"DisableLegacyPointAndPrintAdminSecurityWarning"=dword:00000001
```